# Animating the expanding/collasping of <tbody>: Seeking Some CSS Magic

Tags: javascript, css, animation, sass, stenciljs

I'm currently working on a project where I've got a `<tbody>` element in a table that I can successfully show and hide using JavaScript. However, I'm looking to add a bit more flair to the user experience.

heres a simplified stackblitz of what that looks like:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-w8achg?file=index.html,style.css,index.js

I want to animate the process of the `<tbody>` appearing and disappearing. Ideally, I'd like to achieve this with CSS transitions or animations for a smooth effect. I'm envisioning something like a graceful slide or fade effect, rather than just popping in and out of existence - because everyone deserves a grand entrance, even table bodies!

Could anyone guide me on how to implement this? Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

In my attempts to animate the `<tbody>`, I initially tried wrapping each `<tr>` in a `<div>` inside the `<tbody>`, thinking I could then easily apply the CSS transitions or animations to the `<div>`. However, my IDE flagged an issue, indicating that a `<div>` cannot be a direct child of `<tbody>`. This is in line with HTML standards, where `<tbody>` can only directly contain `<tr>` elements.

Furthermore, when I tried this approach, it unexpectedly affected the alignment of the header columns (the months) in my table. I suspect this might be due to the `<div>`s disrupting the standard table layout, but I'm not entirely sure.

So, I'm looking for alternative methods to smoothly animate the appearance and disappearance of the `<tbody>` content without breaking the table structure. Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this within the constraints of HTML and CSS would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Table rows are quite difficult to animate, due to the impossibility to manipulate their height. However hope this may help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ameuj4?file=index.html,style.css,index.js

Comment: Can this be achieve with css transition?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the given table a smooth effect can be achieved by gradually revealing the body.

This snippet does this by using an after pseudo element on the tfoot which hides the tbody as the tfoot is moved up and reveals it as the tfoot is moved down.

```html
<style>
  h1,
  h2 {
    font-family: Lato;
  }
  
  .table-wrapper {
    margin: 10px;
  }
  
  table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  th,
  td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  input {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  tfoot {
    transform: translateY(calc(-300% + 3px));
    position: relative;
    transition: all 3s linear;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  #toggleButton:checked~table tfoot {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  tfoot::after {
    content: '';
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    height: 400%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 3s linear;
    transform: translateY(-1px);
    border-top: solid 1px black;
  }
  
  #toggleButton:checked~table tfoot::after {
    height: 0;
  }
</style>

<div class="table-wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggleButton">Toggle</button>
  <table>
    <caption>
      Food budget
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>budget month</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="budgetbody">
      <tr>
        <th>Breakfast</th>
        <td>$50</td>
        <td>$60</td>
        <td>$70</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Lunch</th>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>$90</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Dinner</th>
        <td>$110</td>
        <td>$120</td>
        <td>$130</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Total</th>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>300</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

However, there are limitations. We've assumed here that the rows are of equal height, as they are in the example given. Also the full height of the table is there from the start.

To get a more sophisticated method, where the height of the table gradually increases for example, I think you'd have to reintroduce some JS to do calculations on the eventual container height.

A grid rather than a table would be easier to manipulate in CSS, but that would remove the semantics of an HTML table and, depending on the use case, probably not be advisable for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Kudos for mentioning the table semantics!